# Como faço para voltar a commit anteriores de um Branch remoto?

Tags: git

Tenho uma aplicação que possui alguns branchs locais e remotos, só que tive que realizar um `git reset --hard HEAD~1` nos branchs **dev** e **desenvolvimento**(como na imagem abaixo), e cada um desses branchs possuem remoto (**remotes/dev/master** e **remotes/origin/desenvolvimento**, respectivamente) e agora eles ficaram a frente dos branchs locais. Como faço para alinhar os branchs remotos com os locais, ou seja, quero que todos os branch fiquem no commit *"Retirando city dos parametros requiridos"*. É possível?

Imagem do meu repositório local:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obs.: Ao dar um `push` tenho um conflito:

```
! [rejected]        desenvolvimento -> desenvolvimento (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@bitbucket.org:augustoppimenta/recruti.git'
dica: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
dica: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
dica: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
dica: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Comment: vou ter que fazer uns testes aqui, pq eu não entendi direito sua duvia principio já que achei que vc tava passando por uma situação que eu passei recentemente, rs.. enquanto isso vou deletar minha resposta :/

Comment: Beleza então. Muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: @Math Brigadão. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Uma maneira rápida de fazer isso é fazendo um force push depois de ter feito um checkout para o commit que você deseja

Ex.

```
git checkout <commit_hash>
git push origin desenvolvimento --force
```

Essa provavelmente não é a solução ideal se você estiver trabalhando com outras pessoas, visto que a branch local deles estará 2 commits a frente da remota (o que provavelmente vai pedir pra eles enviarem as mudanças novamente para lá), o que eles devem fazer caso isso ocorra é resetar a branch deles para a mesma versão da remota:

```
git reset --hard origin/desenvolvimento
```

Lembre-se que um push forçado remove tudo que está na branch remota e poe o que você tem localmente.. isso pode gerar diversos efeitos indesejados.

A solução ideal seria fazer um revert dos commits que você não quer em cada uma das branchs com o commando:

```
git revert <commit_hash>
```

E então fazer push deles para as branchs remotas

Comment: Olá @yurifariasg, no meu caso eu já um ` git reset`, então eu teria que fazer um `git pull origin ...desenvolvimento` e depois fazer um `git revert`? Daí esse `git revert` já deixaria alinhado o branch local com o branch remoto?

Comment: Se sua branch já estiver alinhada com a remota (feito com um pull ou git reset --hard origin/<branch>), é só fazer o git revert <commit_sha> que o git vai criar um commit NOVO revertendo as mudanças daquele commit... imagine isso como o inverso daquele commit...

Comment: Entendi! Como eu já tinha feito o `-force` tudo deu certo. Caso tenha esse problema novamente já sei como consertar. Muito obrigado pela ajuda. Abraço!

Answer (score 0):

Eu passei pelo mesmo problema hoje mesmo! a solução que achei foi o git revert .
O revert ele cria um novo commit revertendo as alterações feita do commit passando !

Atual commit

```
ccf554115 (HEAD) arrow function over default class react. using new api hook
3196af673 I refator files of gatsby starters for new useStaticQuery
```

Apos `git revert ccf554115`

```
28b9762e9 (HEAD) Revert "arrow function over default class react. using new api hook"
ccf554115 arrow function over default class react. using new api hook
3196af673 I refator files of gatsby starters for new useStaticQuery
```

Depois disto é da um `git push origin < sua branch >`